# Facebook App Token still valid\usable after User Token is expired?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

When I obtain a **FB User Access Token**, it includes an expiry date, 60 days. I'm aware that if the user changes their password or removes my application that the User Access Token will be invalidated.

I am trying to understand the **App Access Token** which documents say **doesn't** expire. In my testing I was still able to use the App Access Token to publish on a FB users behalf even after changing the test FB user password (theoretically, invalidating the User Access Token).

So does this mean that even if the User Access Token expires or the FB user changes their password, as long as they do not uninstall my FB App that I can continue to publish to their FB wall on their behalf ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: App access token as far as i know changes only when there is a update in that app.

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer).  That does two things.  It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist.  See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/187716) for a full explanation"

Comment: _“[…] that I can continue to publish to their FB wall on their behalf ?”_ – yes. And no, under most circumstances you _shouldn’t_. Platform Policies say that you must not post any content that the user has not actively created himself during your app flow … and after sixty days with no user activity in your app (that would give you a new access token), I seriously doubt you have new user-generated content that would fall under this rule.

Answer (score 2):

> even if the User Access Token expires or the FB user changes their password, as long as they do not uninstall my FB App that I can continue to publish to their FB wall on their behalf

**Yes**

> Facebook App Token still valid\usable after User Token is expired?

**Yes**.

There's no such relation between the two tokens. If user changes password- that has nothing to do with the App Access Token. The App Access Token will be invalidated if you change the App Secret of your app. So yes, you can continue to publish to their FB wall on their behalf **until** user did not remove the app or remove the permissions to your app manually in the app settings.

Comment: So what is the need for offline access then?

Comment: @Jimmy Sorry but I cant understand what do you mean, but one thing I know is that offline_access permission has been removed now. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/roadmap/completed-changes/offline-access-removal/